# Handwritten digits recognition during the process of writing

Tags: neural-networks, handwritten-characters

I know how to train a NN for recognizing handwritten digits (e.g. using the MNIST database).

I'm wondering how to accomplish the same "online", which is **during the process of writing** e.g. I'm writing down a digit, and during the process and while keeping "the pen down", the NN recognizes the digit.
To make it simpler, I could assume one stroke-order only for each digit (e.g. each digit is written with a certain order of strokes, like for digit 1 is just a vertical line going up to down).

Which is the most suitable NN for the purpose and how to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried to use a neural network trained on MNIST to achieve that? You can pass the partial input the this NN and observe the output of it and how it evolves.

Comment: @nbro I haven't tried. However it would surely be sub-optimal, as a static partial input lacks "temporal" information (e.g. direction of stroke).

Comment: This is a good point!